# What's the name of that anime that had necklace and gems that summoned fighters

Tags: story-identification, magic, anime, cartoon

The last time I saw that anime I was a kid, so sorry if I'm gonna make some stuff up, I gonna try my best to remember it.

So in the first season, I remember that the story somehow started with a pretty young dude that had a gem that summoned some sort of knight with a spear drill and yellow tint to everything. He was really similar to Orion (from *Brawlhalla*). I can't remember more except that there were people that used magic too...

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is a bit thin on detail; you should check out the [suggestions for anime-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/101407) to see if they help you remember anything else you can [edit] into your question.  If nothing else, the animation style and how long ago this was; we have no idea when you were a kid.

Comment: Spear drill like this; https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/gurennlagann/images/7/7d/Tengen_Toppa_Solvernia_I.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/300?cb=20140628045843?

Comment: Or more like this; https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/kagura/images/b/b0/New_Wave_New_2014_Girl_%284%29.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/210?cb=20140121074654?

Comment: *The last time I saw that anime I was a kid* how old are you? It can be easier to find it if we know you were a kid in the 80's or in 2000 :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess *[Huntik: Secrets & Seekers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntik:_Secrets_%26_Seekers)*

> The series follows Lok Lambert as he uncovers the secret legacy of his missing father. His father, Eathon, was a member of the Huntik Foundation and a part of a secret world of magic users known as Seekers and creatures known as Titans. On his mission to uncover what happened to his father, Lok is joined by Dante Vale, Sophie Casterwill, Zhalia Moon, and a talking Titan called Cherit.[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dgbz.jpg)
>
> Season one focuses on the fight against the evil Organization, led by a powerful Seeker known as the Professor. Along the way, the team discovers the Amulet of Will and the powerful Legendary Titans. Though the Professor eventually acquires the three Legendary Titans of Mind, Body, and Spirit in a bid for immortality, he is defeated by the Huntik team.

It involves summons using a necklace (an amulet) and stones, and other people use magic. While most of the summons seem to wield swords, some of them do wield spears, and most of them wear yellow armor. Here is an image of [Overlos](https://huntik.fandom.com/wiki/Overlos), the Legendary Titan of Immortality:
[image: Overlos, wielding his spear]

I don't see one that's specifically a "drill spear", but there are some funky looking ones. You can see a chart of the summons [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dgbz.jpg). This video shows several of the summons, and the process of summoning them:

### First episode

Comment: Yup that's the one :D, thanks

Comment: @gustas You can accept by clicking the checkmark by the voting buttons.